# What is the simplest 100km RF communication link there is?

Tags: rf, modulation, transmitter, receiver, transceiver

I am looking for a technology for sending sporadic bytes over RF hundreds of kilometers away - assume line of sight. What should I look into to do that? What frequency? What modulation? Perhaps what encoding?
I am looking for the simplest technology around - I don't mind repeating my commands until they are executed. I don't need duplex, just send commands to a distant receiver. I think the power would be limited by what is allowed by the regulations rather than what I can provide.

Application: balloon

Comment: Good question. I'll be following along. I would guess that microwave oven frequencies would be cheapest/easiest. 2.45 GHz or thereabouts. But without the waveguide, it will disperse and I doubt the distance required. A microwave maser would be my second guess. But I don't know much about the current technology. Air is very transparent at about 16 GHz, memory serving. But I'm not sure what's out there at that frequency. Anyway, interesting. Will look forward to good answers here. +1 to the question. (All of the prior is assuming your claim of line-of-sight.) On-off-keying ASK, at a guess.

Comment: What 100 km line of sight target are you talking about?

Comment: You need two masts (transmitting and and receiving end) of over 200m (600ft) high to achieve "line of sight" over 100km. Or are you using a balloon?

Comment: LEO satellite? Most use simple VHF transceivers.

Comment: Spark gap and crystal set. You may not be asking quite the right question...

Comment: To clarify, in case the sarcasm isn't obvious, @user_1818839's suggestion is very illegal.

Comment: Good guess StarCat, I am indeed targeting a balloon

Comment: @user42875 you really really really should have mentioned the balloon application on your question. It makes major differences to potential answers

Comment: Two LORA modules. Appropriate aerials. Done.

Comment: I thought LORA was only good enough for about 10 miles ? What makes you say otherwise?

Comment: @user42875 I may get back to write and answer, but, LORA with proper configuratio is about the longest range system per link budget that you can get. The balloon range record was 714 km (!!!) in Jukly 2019 - see [Here](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/article/lorawan-distance-world-record) . THat's beyond some theoretical calculations but your 100 km is well inside theoretical. ||
For a range limts paper see [here](https://www.smart-city-solutions.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Understanding-the-Limits-of-LoRa.pdf) and ...

Comment: ... a look at [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=lora+maximum+range&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&oq=lora+maximum+range&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i390l5.5199j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) should be rewarding. Adding a decent ground side antenna will help. It's all covered in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343456766_LoRa_24_GHz_Communication_Link_and_Range)  paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LORA WILL do what you want in many cases - and MUCH more if you try hard enough.

**766 km from a balloon.**

LORA with proper configuration is about the longest range system per link budget that you can get. The balloon range record was 714 km (!!!) in July 2019 - see [Here](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/article/lorawan-distance-world-record). That's beyond some theoretical calculations but your 100 km is well inside theoretical.

> 30-07-2019 - After almost 2 years, the world record of 702 km (436 miles) has been broken. Not once but twice. For a long time this record which was set on 26th of August 2017, seemed nearly impossible to break, until the Servet IV mission was launched. On 13th of July 2019, the record was broken by 39 km, setting a new record distance of 741 km. Interestingly, this record only held for 5 hours as another new world record was set with an astonishing distance of 766 km (476 miles).

**__________________________________________**

This is from [LoRa 2.4 GHz Communication Link and Range](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343456766_LoRa_24_GHz_Communication_Link_and_Range)

[image]

---

For a range limts paper see [here](https://www.smart-city-solutions.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Understanding-the-Limits-of-LoRa.pdf) and a look at [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=lora+maximum+range&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&oq=lora+maximum+range&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i390l5.5199j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) should be rewarding.

Adding a decent ground side antenna will help. It's all covered in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343456766_LoRa_24_GHz_Communication_Link_and_Range) paper.

Answer (score 2):

As done before I would go with Packet Radio over VHF. Two directional yagi antennas, two radios and two modems. would work like a charm if LOS. With only a watt or two of power and intermittent sending of required short data bursts the setup could be solar powered. Also make sure to find a channel which does not get much traffic.

Please note that due to curvature of the earth you will have to have one of the antennas at aprox 785m above mean sea level if other one is at 0m. Not accounting for fresnel zone. which could be as wide as 250m at this range and frequency.
360deg / 40030km(earth circumference) = 0.009deg/km so Angle for 100km =0.9deg
height for LOS  = radiusEarth * (1 - cos (Angle of great circle)) = 785m

Comment: Thanks! Could you expand on the technologies I should look into within VHF packet radios? It looks like it's qui a large family and I am not sure all of them comply with 100km range. Ideally I'd like something close to those bluetooth modules on which we receive exactly what we sent, but I am willing to do more efforts as long as it is the simplest I can do. I am targeting a balloon, so the curvature of the earth has little importance.